# Nested Conditional Properties for Local file references not working in python-jsonschema

Tags: jsonschema, json-schema-validator, python-jsonschema

My `RefResolver` and `Validator` script is

```
from jsonschema import RefResolver
from jsonschema.validators import validator_for
from tests.automation.io.helpers.loader import load_schema

base = load_schema('base.schema.json') # {"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#" }
definitions = load_schema('defination.schema.json') # https://jsonschema.dev/s/FZDbO
schema = load_schema('update.schema.json') # https://jsonschema.dev/s/lvLFa

schema_store = {
  base.get('$id','base.schema.json') : base,
  definitions.get('$id','defination.schema.json') : definitions,
  schema.get('$id','update.schema.json') : schema,
}

resolver = RefResolver.from_schema(base, store=schema_store)
Validator = validator_for(base)
validator = Validator(schema, resolver=resolver)

data = {
    "common_data": {
        "os_ip": "127.0.0.1",
        "os_user": "root",
        "os_pwd": "hello",
        "remote_os": "Windows"
    },
    "dup_file": "ad7a.exe"
}
validator.validate(data)
```

My JSON Schema looks like

`base.schema.json` => `{"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#" }`

`defination.schema.json` =>  https://jsonschema.dev/s/FZDbO

`update.schema.json` => https://jsonschema.dev/s/lvLFa

Getting error : `jsonschema.exceptions.ValidationError: 'ad7a.exe' does not match '^(.*.)(bin)$'`

Same thing I have tested https://json-schema.hyperjump.io/ it working perfectly fine , suspecting some issue with `python-jsonschema` only.

Comment: I don't see `'^(.*.)(bin)$'` in your schema anywhere. I don't think anyone can provide help for schemas they can't see.

Comment: @Ether thanks for the feedback. Actually I have mentioned JSON schema's beside the `load_schema` function as `#` for better understanding (live demo). I have updated the post also at the same time .

Comment: If anyone was able to reproduce the issue. I am thinking of using some other JSON schema validator. Suggestions pls.